# Automaticaly add script to google document with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

We have writen a script that imports a microsoft word document, converts it to a google docs document and updates the content.

Now we want to add a custom toolbar with custom functions.
We do this manualy by opening the script editor, **but this is too much work.**

We want to add the scripts automaticaly on creating the document, how can we do this?

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script-api/info) for more details.

Comment: For documentation reasons please accept the answer that helped you or provide a feedback so I can modify the answer to solve your question.

Answer (score 1):

- You need an [onOpen()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) function to create a toolbar ([custom
  menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)) in Google Apps Script.

Assuming that you want to create a toolbar with the name `Toolbar`, a button with the name `Execute script` to execute a function with the name `myFunction`, try the following:

```
function onOpen() {
      // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Toolbar')
      .addItem('Execute script', 'myFunction')
      .addToUi();
    }
```